# Calling gcc with shell_exec in php

Tags: php, gcc, compiler-construction, shell-exec

```
<?php
$output=shell_exec('gcc prog.c');
echo "$output";
?>
```

I'm trying execute a c program using php and have used shell_exec to call gcc to execute the program but it is giving no output but there is no error being showed . Can please someone correct the mistake 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: is gcc in the path of whatever shell php is invoking? is prog.c in the same directory as this script? does the webserver UID have permission to write files in this directory?

Comment: the script and prog are in the same directory but how to check for other two things?

Comment: If the program compiles fine, there shouldn't be any output from `gcc` and therefore no output to your application. Does it compile when you run `gcc prog.c` manually from command-line and/or does it give any output?

Comment: it is compiling in terminal but not giving any output , what should i do to get the outpu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc is used to compile the c file.  It doesn't 'run' the .c file.  Try it from your command line.  You will notice after running gcc prog.c you have a file named 'a.out'.  a.out is the executable that is created from the successful compile of prog.c

Comment: `<?php
$output=shell_exec('/path/to/executable/a.out');
echo "$output";
?>`

Answer (score 0):

Calling `gcc` will launch a compile of the `prog.c` file. It's not executing it.

If you need your `prog.c` file to be compiled at runtime, I'd write a quick shell script that would look somewhat like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm prog_compiled_from_php               # Remove previously compiled program
GCC=`which gcc`                         # Find the path to gcc and store it in the "GCC" variable
$GCC prog.c -o prog_compiled_from_php   # Compile prog.c into the binary called prog_compiled_from_php
./prog_compiled_from_php                # Execute the compiled program
```

Save this file as `prog_compile`

Make sure you make this script executable, with this: `chmod a+x prog_compile`

From PHP, call `$output = shell_exec('prog_compile');`

I'm no bash script expert, feel free to correct my syntax :)

Comment: I wrote a bash script. Assuming you're running PHP on a *nix box, you can run the bash script instead of the command you posted. I'll add explanations of what the script does.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute many cmd commands using `&&`.
To compile the C file and execute and echo the output, you can use this line of code :

```
$output = shell_exec('cd /path/to/c_file && gcc prog.c && a');
echo '&output';
```