# How to setup gcc compiler on server side and ask it to run codes uploaded by client?

Tags: php, gcc

An online C/C++ compiler is to be made where clients can upload their codes on the server side and the server runs it using gcc compiler.
The main problem is how to setup gcc in local server and command it to run the code and return the results to the client?

Comment: I think that this is a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806365/calling-gcc-with-shell-exec-in-php

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach to this does not require any particular setup for gcc. You just have to retrieve the uploaded file(s), place it in a certain directory and invoke `gcc <flags> mycode.cxx -o mycode` (using, for instance, `shell_exec`, as pointed in some other answers) or whatever compilation steps you want to perform from there. A nice idea would be to check gcc's `stdout` and `stderr` as well as of course the exit code of the subprocess. If everything goes well, the resulting executable will be in the place you ask `gcc` to put it, so you just have to read it and retrieve it.

Note that this is an over-simplified description of the problem: it does not handle long compilation times that might result in timeouts, nor does it consider security concerns (if any) that might arise, but I hope it can help you start drafting something.

As an alternative to that, I would recommend you to have a look at [distcc](https://cdn.rawgit.com/distcc/distcc/9a09372bd3f420cdd7021e52eda14fa536a3c10e/doc/web/index.html). It is rather easy to set up, has authentication options, balancing between machines, etc and is very customizable. It also makes the process a bit simpler to your users, as they only need to replace `gcc ...` to `distcc ...` in their terminals when they want to compile something (after configuration, of course).